# In ggplot 2, how to connect the start and the end points in geom_line

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to connect three dots "a", "b" and "c" using geom_line, but it only connects "ab" and "bc", but not "ca", how can I achieve that using geom_line or geom_path, rather than geom_polygon?

```
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame (line =c ("a", "b", "c"), x = c(1, 2, 3), y = c(5, 2, 5))

ggplot() +
geom_path(data = df, aes (x = x, y = y, color = line))
```

Comment: Great question! So, do you want the legend as well? Did you try it? If so, please share your code.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to repeat the first row at the end to get a closing polygon without using `geom_polygon`.

```
ggplot(rbind(df, head(df, 1)), aes(x = x, y = y, color = line, group = 1)) + 
  geom_path()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way you can do it by adding the first point in your vector to draw a line segment parallel to the x-axis. Essentially, you would need to give complete path to `geom_path` if you want to create a polygon.

Note: line d:

```
df <- data.frame (line =c ("a", "b", "c","d"), x = c(1, 2, 3,1), y = c(5, 2, 5,5))

     ggplot ()+
       geom_path(data = df, aes (x = x, y = y))
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It works but it is still a little tricky, especially when I use the legend.